# how to make a text field transparent in android

Tags: android, textbox

I want to make a text box transparent so that the underlying image should be visible.
But the text typed in it should be visible.

My code is here

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="image" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.53"
        android:text="overlap" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.82" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="211dp"
        android:layout_x="30dp"
        android:layout_y="42dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus >
        </requestFocus>
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="88dp"
        android:layout_y="81dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img1" >
    </ImageView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

And this xml code to the textView , you want to make transparent

**android:background="#00000000"**

hexa value for transparentcolor is #00000000

Answer (score 2):

// in other way you can make it to null background

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        ...
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />
```

You can always handle transparency of color using two digits forwarding the color code.Like:

For red color,you can use #00FF0000,#22FF0000,#70FF0000 etc. for various transparency of red color. 00 will be 100% transparency and 99 would be 99% opaqueness.